select dataframe column and replace values by indices if True
Hard to find the right title...here is what I want:
I have a dataframe and a column col1 with values : val1, val2, val3
I want to select the rows with val2 or val3 values for this specific column and replace them with val4 value but not for all of them, just for a "slice" between idx x and y :
import pandas as pd
data = {'col1':["val1","val3","val3","val2","val1","val2","val3","val1"],'col2':["val3","val1","val2","val1","val2","val3","val2","val2"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
   col1  col2
0  val1  val3
1  val3  val1
2  val3  val2
3  val2  val1
4  val1  val2
5  val2  val3
6  val3  val2
7  val1  val2

Select rows from col1 with val2 or val3 values :
(df['col1']=="val2") | (df['col1']=="val3")
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6     True
7    False

Now I want to replace the first 4 True rows for col1 (rows with index 1 2 3 5) with val4 in order to obtain :
   col1  col2
0  val1  val3
1  val4  val1
2  val4  val2
3  val4  val1
4  val1  val2
5  val4  val3
6  val3  val2
7  val1  val2

I thought something like :
df[((df['col1']=="val2") | (df['col1']=="val3"))==True][0:4] = "val4"
but it doesn't work (not surprise...)
Thought I need to use something like .loc
Thanx for any clue

You can get the rows based on the condition
condition = (df['col1'] == "val2") | (df['col1'] == "val3")

And then get indices of rows that match the condition
indices = df[condition].index[:4]

Finally use loc to replace the selected rows with val4
df.loc[indices, 'col1'] = 'val4'

Output
   col1  col2
0  val1  val3
1  val4  val1
2  val4  val2
3  val4  val1
4  val1  val2
5  val4  val3
6  val3  val2
7  val1  val2


Thanx for this solution, I modified the "condition" with the isin function

Create a boolean map to select positions with the specified values. Then, use this map to get the first 4 indexes of the original frame where the values are True. Use those indexes with df.loc to locate the positions you want to modify.
selectted_val = df['col1'].isin(['val2','val3'])
first_four = df.index[selectted_val][:4]
df.loc[first_four, 'col1'] = 'val4'


One drawback of this this otherwise fine approach, is that it wouldn't work if you have duplicated indices.

isin is better than my OR and mask approach is fine, thanx for the clue

Assign your mask to a variable, and use cumsum to enumerate the positions, then combine with the mask with & to only select the desired numeric range:
m = df['col1'].isin(['val2', 'val3'])

df.loc[m&m.cumsum().le(4), 'col1'] = 'val4'

The advantage of this approach is that it will work independently of the values in the index. It would for example tolerate duplicated indices.
Output:
   col1  col2
0  val1  val3
1  val4  val1
2  val4  val2
3  val4  val1
4  val1  val2
5  val4  val3
6  val3  val2
7  val1  val2

Intermediates:
   col1  col2      m  cumsum  le(4)      &
0  val1  val3  False       0   True  False
1  val3  val1   True       1   True   True
2  val3  val2   True       2   True   True
3  val2  val1   True       3   True   True
4  val1  val2  False       3   True  False
5  val2  val3   True       4   True   True
6  val3  val2   True       5  False  False
7  val1  val2  False       5  False  False

One-liner variant using where:
df.loc[(df['col1'].isin(['val2', 'val3'])
       .where(lambda x: x)
       .cumsum().le(4)
       ), 'col1'] = 'val4'


You can define the mask with your 2 conditions and then use .loc:
x, y = 1, 5
mask = df["col1"].isin(["val2", "val3"]) & df.index.isin(range(x, y+1))
df.loc[mask, "col1"] = "val4"
display(df)



I needed indices from 1 to 4, you defined x to 0 and y to 5 then range on x and y+1, a little bit confusing for me...

@Fabrice, unlike other answers I believe I wanted to make my answer more general as you wrote " for a "slice" between idx x and y". My solution works for any range and here I choose x and y as for your example  (index between x=1 and y=5 as you wrote). list(range(1, 5+1)) = list(range(1, 6)) = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] . But no problem if you prefer another solution :-)
